# What fractions do I multiply to solve this probability problem?

Tags: probability

*A 10 faced die is rolled repeatedly until it lands on a 7. What is the probability to the nearest whole that it takes exactly 5 rolls for it to land on a 7?*

What formula should I use to answer this problem? All I know is that there is 1/10 chance of landing a 7 once and that the answer is 7%.

But how do I calculate the probability for getting a specific result after an **exact** number of rolls?

Comment: If to the nearest whole means to the nearest whole number, you can answer $0$ without  thinking.  It is clearly not greater than $\frac 12$

Comment: @almagest:  my comment applies even if the die is not fair, as long as the chance of a $7$ does not change between rolls.  If the chance of a $7$ is greater than $\frac 12$ the chance of taking $5$ rolls is less than $\frac 12$ because you will stop at the first roll most of the time.  If the chance of $7$ is less than $\frac 12$ the chance of getting it on roll $5$ will be less than $\frac 12$

Comment: OP probability meant "nearest whole percent"

Comment: @RossMillikan Hmmm. This question was (quite unintentionally, I suspect) much subtler than it looked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of dice rolling anything other than 7 in 4 turns will be: ${({9\over 10})}^4$

Probability of rolling 7 on the 5th turn is: ${1\over 10}$

Total probability $= {{9^4}\over {10^5}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You have to get four rolls in a row that are not $7$ followed by a $7$.

Comment: So would it be (9/10)^4?

Comment: That gets you the four in a row, but not the $7$

Comment: I'm not sure what formula applies to this specific type of case...

Comment: You multiply your $(\frac 9{10})^4$ by $\frac 1{10}$  for the chance you get the $7$ on the fifth roll.